# How to return errors when Ajax passes parameter to controller and model is invalid due to data annotations?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have an ajax post that calls a controller action and passes a parameter that was entered by the user (me).

I'm using data annotations to validate the model in the controller action. If I enter an invalid value (or no value) and run the ajax:

- The controller action is called
- The model is found to be invalid (as expected)
- The variable "result" is defined as expected and contains the model, errors, etc.

**Problem:** The return is seemingly ignored and 500 (Internal Server Error) is the response.

At this point I would be okay setting the status code to 200 to handle the errors in the success call back, but I have not been able to override it with this (in controller action):

```
HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
```

and this (in web.config):

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="PassThrough"/>
```

I would also be fine returning an object to the error callback provided I could retrieve the model's errors from it, but that doesn't seem possible from what I have read.

I have searched through so many posts and blogs that seem applicable only to find the same handful of solutions that I'm not quite able to apply (either technically or conceptually).

**Question:** How can I keep data annotations on the parameter that I pass to the controller and enforce the return of some kind of object containing the model errors?

**Ajax:**

```
$('#apply-theme-color-btn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var themeColor = $('#ThemeColor').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Manage/ChangeThemeColor/' + themeColor,
        type: "POST",
        //dataType: "text",
        data: {"themeColor": themeColor}, //.serialize(),
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#apply-theme-color-btn').toggleClass('active');
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (data.IsValid) {
                console.log('Success');
            }
            else {
                console.log(data);
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('Error');
        },
        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            $('#apply-theme-color-btn').toggleClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Manage/ChangeThemeColor/{themeColor:string}")]
public ActionResult ChangeThemeColor(string themeColor, IndexViewModel model) {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        var result = Json(new { IsValid = false, model = model, errors = ModelState.Values.Where(i => i.Errors.Count > 0) });
        return result;
    }
    else {
        //Do some different stuff
        }
    }
```

**Model:**

```
...
[Required]
[StringLength(7, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 7)]
public string ThemeColor { get; set; }
```

Comment: Your post method makes no sense - its has a parameter `IndexViewModel model` but your not passing back a model (or does that model contain a property `themeColor` - in which case remove the first parameter). And why are you adding the vale to both the url and data in the ajax options?

Comment: Thanks - I am working through some misconceptions now. I may have been distracted from the real issue(s) for several reasons. If the method receives only the model, and the route attribute is removed, and the ajax url is fixed to only '/Manage/ChangeThemeColor':

- if I exclude the data section of ajax I can get the json object with errors (of course it errors though, there is no themeColor)

- if I include the data section, I still get 500 on invalid model

So I'm still investigating, but I'm likely looking at the right thing now - thanks.

Comment: `500 (internal Server Error)` almost always means your throwing an exception in the controller method (another cause can be setting the wrong `dataType` but you have commented that out). Use you browser tools (Network tab) to inspect the response - it will give you the details of the exception

Comment: I did not take notice of the network tab. Inside was `"A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo'"`... which turned out to be caused by this part of my action:  `errors = ModelState.Values.Where(i => i.Errors.Count > 0)`... I can return the errors some other way now that I understand 500 was the real problem status code (an exception in fact), and had nothing to do with data annotations. My post and action are cleaned up, and I'm able to return json for both valid and invalid model states. Amazing. Thanks very much!

Comment: What I suspect you really want is `errors = ModelState.Keys.Where(k => ModelState[k].Errors.Count > 0).Select(k => new { propertyName = k, errorMessage = ModelState[k].Errors[0].ErrorMessage });` which will give you each property name and its associated error message (and there is no need to return the model that the client just sent to the server)

Comment: That's where I'll be heading, yep. The other code for grabbing the errors was a drive by copy/paste. Would have reviewed it sooner but had no idea it was an issue until looking at network tab. I just tried your loops. Yep, solid. Is there some way I can give you points for answering my question (which I guess should have really been written "Why does controller action return status code 500")?

Comment: I'll add an answer in an hour or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`500 (Internal Server Error)` means that your throwing an exception in the controller method, in your case a circular reference exception as noted in the comments.

To return a collection of errors for invalid properties, use

```
errors = ModelState.Keys.Where(k => ModelState[k].Errors.Count > 0)
    .Select(k => new { propertyName = k, errorMessage = ModelState[k].Errors[0].ErrorMessage })
```

which will return the property name and the associated error message of all invalid property values.

Side notes:

1. `url: '/Manage/ChangeThemeColor/' + themeColor,` should be just
   `url: '/Manage/ChangeThemeColor',` since you already passing
   `themeColor` in the `data:` option (or better still
   `@Url.Action("ChangeThemeColor", "Manage")',`)
2. Since `IndexViewModel` contains property `ThemeColor`, there is not
   need for the parameter in your method and it should be just `public
   ActionResult ChangeThemeColor(IndexViewModel model)`
3. There is no need to send back the same model back to the client that
   the client just sent to the controller (remove `model = model"` from
   the `return Json()` statement.